# keypress - escape doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

```
$(el).bind('blur keypress', function(event){


  if(event.type == 'keypress' && event.keyCode != 13) return;
  alert(1);

});
```

I get the alert box even when I press escape, and I shouldn;t because I only allowed Enter...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default "**return**" will send the called function the value true, so in this case the default event is allowed to be performed so whatever button u press u will get the alert. So change the **return** statement as **return false**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only allow `Enter` then try this. Check for `true` condition it will make more clear to you. Also instead of `e.keyCode` you can use `e.which`, it is abstracted by `jQuery` to make it corss browser compatible.

```
$(el).bind('blur keypress', function(event){
  if(event.type == 'keypress' && event.which == 13){
      alert(1);
  }
});
```